# Why json showing array index and array object multiple times in eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

My JSON output is like:

```
{
    "0": "1",
    "1": "araer",
    "2": "aeraer",
    "3": "aeraer",
    "4": "News/Magzine Website",
    "5": "2016-01-22 13:15:56",
    "6": "2016-01-22 13:15:56",
    "id": "1",
    "name": "araer",
    "email": "aeraer",
    "url": "aeraer",
    "web": "News/Magzine Website",
    "created_at": "2016-01-22 13:15:56",
    "updated_at": "2016-01-22 13:15:56"
}, {
    "0": "2",
    "1": "asd",
    "2": "asd",
    "3": "sfd",
    "4": "sdf",
    "5": "2016-02-10 13:06:28",
    "6": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "id": "2",
    "name": "asd",
    "email": "asd",
    "url": "sfd",
    "web": "sdf",
    "created_at": "2016-02-10 13:06:28",
    "updated_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00"
}
```

The code I am using in Model:

```
public function getBlog() {
    try {
        $result = $this - > get();
        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return array();
    }
    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check PDO fetch style in your config/databse.php array. If it is not present there then it will use PDO::FETCH_BOTH (by default) which returns both associative and numeric values. To get only associative value you need to set `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,` or `'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Answer (score 0):

You function will retutn all records from your blog table.
And if you want to get single record then try something like

```
$this->get()->first();
```

Comment: Table have only one unique record, which is showing two time in json with array index as well as array object